# One more tidyr, gather and use of variables

Tags: r, variables, tidyr

Here is my code:

```
library(tidyr)

messy <- data.frame(
  name = c("Wilbur", "Petunia", "Gregory"),
  a = c(67, 80, 64),
  b = c(56, 90, 50)
)
```

And I would like to use `gather` function with variable/function result. Borrowing [from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31136536/how-can-tidyr-spread-function-take-variable-as-a-select-column) I tried:

```
not_messy <-messy %>%
  gather_('drug', 'heartrate', paste0('a',''):paste0('b',''))
```

But it generated error:

```
Error in paste0("a", ""):paste0("b", "") : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In lapply(.x, .f, ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In lapply(.x, .f, ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the latest version of the tidyverse functions, you are discouraged from using the underscore versions of the function for standard evaluation and instead use the rlang function syntax. In this case you can use

```
gather(messy, "drug", "heartrate", (!!as.name("a")):(!!as.name("b")))
```

Comment: Quick question. Does the same approach with with `rename` from `dplyr`

Comment: It should. If you have problems feel free to post a new question, but look around this site first because these types of questions are somewhat common.